# How to clear/reset results of the Python line profiler?

Tags: python, performance, profiling, line-profiler

I'm trying to start and stop the [line profiling](https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler) of a Python function multiple times during runtime. Therefore I'd like to reset the already collected stats when starting a new profiling. Is there a way to do that?

In lack of an obvious solution I also tried replacing the line profiler `lp` with a fresh instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from line_profiler import LineProfiler

lp = LineProfiler()

@lp
def count():
    return sum(range(1_000_000))

count()
lp.print_stats()

# reset line profiler
new_lp = LineProfiler()
for f in lp.functions:
    new_lp(f)
lp = new_lp

count()
lp.print_stats()
```

But somehow the new stats are empty, possibly because the function `count()` can't be wrapped twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following solution based of a new profiler class. Every time a profiling is started, it creates a new instance of `LineProfiler`. The key is to store wrapped functions next to the originals, so that they can be reset when stopping the profiler.

```py
from typing import Optional
from line_profiler import LineProfiler
from functools import wraps

class MyLineProfiler:

    def __init__(self):
        self.functions: list[list] = []
        self.line_profiler: Optional[LineProfiler] = None

    def __call__(self, func):
        index = len(self.functions)

        @wraps(func)
        def wrap(*args, **kw):
            return self.functions[index][1](*args, **kw)

        self.functions.append([func, func])
        return wrap

    def start(self):
        self.line_profiler = LineProfiler()
        for f in self.functions:
            f[1] = self.line_profiler(f[0])

    def stop(self, *, print: bool = True):
        for f in self.functions:
            f[1] = f[0]
        if self.line_profiler and print:
            self.line_profiler.print_stats()

    def reset(self):
        self.stop(print=False)
        self.start()
```

The wrapped functions call whatever is currently stored at `functions[index][1]`, either the original `func` (when no profiling is stopped) or the decorated one (when `start()` was called).

It can be used as follows:

```py
profile = MyLineProfiler()

@profile
def count():
    return sum(range(1_000_000))

count()

profile.start()
count()
count()
profile.stop()

profile.start()
count()
profile.stop()
```